# How do I use string formatter to restrain two digits before decimal point and two digits after in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

I'm well aware that if you want to force two digits, you do

```
"%2d" % blah
```

And if in a scenario that it is necessary to enforce two digits after decimal point, you do

```
".2f" % blah
```

I'm a bit confused on what should I do in order to combine those two together? Which is to say, 4.6 will be rendered as 04.60, and 34.274 will still be rendered as 34.27.

Apparently

```
"%2d.2f" % blah
```

doesn't work.

I'm thinking that I should probably go for

```
"%2d%.2f" % [bla_first_half, blah_second_half]
```

but I'm kind of reluctant to do so since it's a bit tedious.

I know if Java one can easily do

```
"##.##"
```

So is there any ruby counterpart like that? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"%05.2f" % 4.66   # => 04.66
"%05.2f" % 34.274 # => 34.27
```

1. `.2f` means the float will be rounded to only two digits after the `.`
2. `05` means the string will be no less than *5* characters and if there are less - it will fill the missing ones with `0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. However `"05.2f" % 34.274 # => 34.27` :) I'd like to give you an upvote but I still haven't got 50 reputation points, so sorry :(

Comment: @宋楚宁, isn't this exactly what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah. I'm referring to your answer and there's a minor fault. Or should I edit it directly? Sorry this is my first time asking here.

Comment: @宋楚宁, I fixed that. Btw you don't have to upvote it, just accept the answer as correct (assuming it exactly answers your question) by pressing the ✔.